# vim: hide status line in the bottom

Tags: vim, configuration

Sometimes I work with really small terminal windows and need every piece of space available. So I want to hide the vim status line.

I already `set laststatus=0` this hides one of the status lines. But there is still another one with the content `-- INSERT --` and `"filename.ext" 22L 500C`.

How can I hide this line?

Comment: That line is called the "command line". Same on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770413/remove-vim-bottom-line-with-mode-line-column-etc Autohide request: http://superuser.com/questions/619765/hiding-vim-command-line-when-its-not-being-used

Comment: @Ciro, no. Status line is correct: http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/17.html

Answer (score 24):

Add these lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
let s:hidden_all = 0
function! ToggleHiddenAll()
    if s:hidden_all  == 0
        let s:hidden_all = 1
        set noshowmode
        set noruler
        set laststatus=0
        set noshowcmd
    else
        let s:hidden_all = 0
        set showmode
        set ruler
        set laststatus=2
        set showcmd
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <S-h> :call ToggleHiddenAll()<CR>
```

Then in normal mode, type `Shift + H` to hide all, type again to make them visible.

You can change `<S-h>` to any key you want.

Comment: Thank you, this is already a good step. But the status line still exists. It says `"filename.ext" 22L 500C` when I start vim.

Comment: @ph3nx: What happen when you type `Shift + H`

Comment: Then messages like `-- INSERT --` are not shown anymore, but the line still exists and says `"filename.ext" 22L 500C`.

Comment: In order to get rid of the fileinfo in the command line, you can put:
`set shortmess=F` in your vimrc. I recommend reading `:help shortmess`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else comes here looking for how to disable the status bar (top one of the 2 bars)

Supposedly `set laststatus=0` should work. However I noticed this was not working in my `vimrc` but would work if set manually for each vim session.

To resolve this issue, I added an `autocmd` within my `.vimrc` to override any existing laststatus setting:

```
# ~/.vimrc

" Hide Status Line
set laststatus=0 " For some reason this doesnt work
autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * set laststatus=0 " This will work instead
```

Answer (score 0):

The `noshowmode` setting hides the messages such as `--Insert--`, `--Replace--`, `--Visual--`, etc. from your last line in `insert`, `replace` and `visual` mode.

```
set noshowmode
```